# ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined

Tags: github-actions

I have been using the following code in my GitHub Actions workflow to trigger an update in the parent repository:

```yaml
- name: Send Trigger to Parent Repository
  uses: actions/github-script@v6.3.3
  with:
    script: |
      const { Octokit } = require("@octokit/action");
      const octokit = new Octokit
      ({
        auth: '${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
      })
      await octokit.rest.repos.createDispatchEvent
      ({
        owner: '${{ github.repository_owner }}',
        repo: '${{ matrix.parent_repo_name }}',
        event_type: '${{ env.EVENT_TYPE }}',
        client_payload: {
          submodule_name: '${{ github.event.repository.name }}',
          commit_message: `${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}`
        }
      });
```

Yesterday, I started getting the following error:

```
Error: Unhandled error: ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/{REPO_NAME}/{REPO_NAME}/node_modules/undici/index.js:118:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
```

I have made no changes to this code in nearly a year. What is causing this new issue? What is the quickest way to solve this?

Comment: octokit/action https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octokit/action?activeTab=readme was updated yesterday, maybe is breaks something

Comment: @sagstetterC Is there a way for me to target an older version?

Comment: idk. but maybe it helps when you change actions/github-script@v6.3.3 to actions/github-script@v6 https://github.com/actions/github-script/compare/v6.3.3...v6.4.1